# Is it bad practice to call a DB function for all of my returns?

Tags: node.js, express, psql, kysely

I'm working on a Node/Express/PSQL/Kysely backend. I have an employees route where a majority of the time the server is going to send the employee with the same object structure. Is it bad practice to call a DB function (getEmployeeById) for all of my returns? I feel like I'm making more database calls then needed but want my return value to be structured the same across all requests. EX: In my createEmployee and UpdateEmployee functions I already have access to the employee when running my insert or update query, I could technically get the values I need from there using "RETURNING" in my query but if I ever want to change the structure of that return I'd have to update it in every function. This is why I opted to use a getEmployeeById for my return value.

```
export async function createEmployee(employee: NewEmployee, roles: Roles) {
  try {
    if (!employee || !roles) {
      throw new CustomError(400, 'Invalid data supplied');
    }
    const newEmployeeId = await db.transaction().execute(async (trx) => {
      const newEmployee = await trx
        .insertInto('employees')
        .values(employee)
        .returning(['id', 'name', 'email', 'username', 'create_date'])
        .executeTakeFirstOrThrow();

      for (let role in roles) {
        if (roles[role as keyof Roles]) {
          await trx
            .insertInto('employee_roles')
            .values({
              employee_id: newEmployee.id,
              role_id: role,
            })
            .execute();
        }
      }
      return newEmployee.id;
    });
    return await getEmployeeById(newEmployeeId);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

export async function updateEmployee(id: number, employee: EmployeeUpdate, roles: Roles | null) {
  try {
    await db.transaction().execute(async (trx) => {
      await trx
        .updateTable('employees')
        .set(employee)
        .where('id', '=', id)
        .returning(['id', 'name', 'email', 'username', 'create_date'])
        .executeTakeFirstOrThrow();
      if (!roles) return;

      for (let role in roles) {
        if (roles[role as keyof Roles]) {
          const doesRoleExist = await trx
            .selectFrom('employee_roles')
            .select('role_id')
            .where('role_id', '=', role)
            .executeTakeFirst();
          if (!doesRoleExist) {
            throw new CustomError(401, `Role ${role} does not exist`);
          }
          const existingRole = await trx
            .selectFrom('employee_roles')
            .select(['employee_id', 'role_id'])
            .where('employee_id', '=', id)
            .where('role_id', '=', role)
            .executeTakeFirst();
          if (!existingRole) {
            await trx
              .insertInto('employee_roles')
              .values({
                employee_id: id,
                role_id: role,
              })
              .execute();
          }
        } else {
          await trx.deleteFrom('employee_roles').where('employee_id', '=', id).where('role_id', '=', role).execute();
        }
      }
    });
    return await getEmployeeById(id);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, as you mentioned, this an inefficient/unnenecessary query to retrieve newly inserted or updated data. If your data isn't going to be modified while inserting or updating, you can simply use the data you received from these transactions.